# Old link doesn't work for a good answer

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers, old-questions

There are many old answers on stackoverflow, sometimes they link to page which has been deleted or not found (cause it is old )

see this [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918/can-i-access-asp-net-development-server-in-an-intranet) and its answer.**(as an example i faced..)**

maybe some answers need to re-edit by owners for adding another link?

or answers should just stay as good answers with not working links?

Comment: It's always worth checking the [Wayback Machine for lost gems](http://web.archive.org/web/20120828023957/http://jcbserver.uwaterloo.ca/cs436/software/tgui/tcpTunnelGUI.shtml) - it would increase the longevity of the answer in this case though I do find the service to be a little fragile so if you wish to edit it I'd consider extracting the the most relevant parts and putting them into the post itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called "link rot" and is exactly the reason why link-only answers are not allowed.

For these you should do your best to find the linked resource and fix the link by editing the question.

If the answer depended on the link, and you cannot fix it and the answer is effectively useless without it then you can flag it as Not an answer. If the answer still has some merit without the link then consider editing in a note to say the link is dead, or at least leave that as a comment.

For your example question maybe [this SourceForge project](http://javatunnel.sourceforge.net/) is now the correct location?